# Splitting character string inside a List and deleting the second element in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, unique, strsplit

I am having problems working with a dataframe in R.
I have downloaded a table of the world happiness report from wikipedia.
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report
However the table took every name of the country and printed it twice. "China China" ...
How do I get rid of the duplicate?

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

link <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report"

df <- read_html(link) %>%
html_element("table.wikitable") %>%
html_table()
```

This is what I tried so far:

`df$Land <- lapply(df$Land, function(x) unique(str_split(x, " ")[[1]]))`

However if I print "df" I get " <chr [1]> " in the "Land" column.
If i just print df$Land I get all country names just as I had them at the beginning:
[[1]]
[1] "Finnland Finnland"

Almost  the same happens when I tried:

`df$Land <- unique(str_split(df$Land, " +")[[1]])`

Can someone please help me or show me a place where the question has already been answered?
Thank you

Comment: You are extraacting the first list element.  Instead, you may need `unique(unlist(str_split(x, " ")))`

Comment: Also, the space seems to be unicode, Thus, it may not be matching correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the wikipedia page, you can see these aren't duplicates but the names of the icons in that column which are enclosed in `<span>` tags. These are then coerced to text using `html_table()`. You could remove the icons from the data before you apply `html_table()`:

```
library(xml2)
link <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report"
raw_data <- read_html(link)
spans <- raw_data %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*/tr/td/span")
xml2::xml_remove(spans)
df <- raw_data %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table') %>%
  html_table() 
df[[1]]
```